# How to deal with date picker in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I'm trying to select a range of dates from a date picker like [this](https://demo.improvely.com/reports/webshop/ads?imt=1&utm_campaign=Date%20Range%20Picker&utm_source=Site%20Ads&utm_medium=Banner&utm_content=Blog%20Demo%20Image) using selenium in python

Ex: Select date range today()+1 to today()+10 days

Currently, I am able to open this page click on the calendar and then click on the custom date. After which my next step would be to select the date range and click apply.
Below is the code:

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import date, timedelta

browser = webdriver.Chrome('*driver path*')
browser.get('https://demo.improvely.com/reports/webshop/ads?imt=1&utm_campaign=Date+Range+Picker&utm_source=Site+Ads&utm_medium=Banner&utm_content=Blog+Demo+Image')

date_picker = browser.find_element_by_id('daterange').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/ul/li[7]").click()
today = date.today()
from_date = today + timedelta(days=1)
to_date = today + timedelta(days=10)
```

`

Please help me out with a solution to get this done.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below xpath will give you all the dates in current month

```
 elements = driverInstance.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='calendar left']/descendant::*[@class='table-condensed']/child::*[2]/descendant::*")
```

> Traverse through all the dates and select desired one.

```
for dates in elements:
Selectdate = dates.get_attribute("innerText")
 if Selectdate== from_date:
     dates.click()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Amruta Pande!

Your answer has not only helped me with this challenge but also opened gates for my next steps after I started digging around XPath.